# Is it possible to preserve quotations by storing $@ into another variable?

Tags: bash, quotation-marks

If I have this on the command line:

```
bin/my_file --name "this name with whitespace" dir/some_file
```

Then in my script:

```
full_cmd="$@"
# later...
"$full_cmd"
```

The quotation marks are not preserved. This is the closest I've come:

```
 app=$1
 shift
 $app "$@"
```

However, it would be convenient if it were possible to save the "$@" into a variable to re-use later, like this:

```
 my_func () {
    $app "$args"
 }
```

I haven't been able to make any of that work... other than messy `for loops`.  I'm new to bash.  I've search all other possible solutions and can't figure out why this is so hard. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@choroba answer is good but you need to know that $0 is not in $@. As well here is an alternative:

```
printf -v myvar '%q ' "$@"
```

Then you have the strings shell escaped and thus will be correctly interpreted as separate arguments. And let me not forget - you need to use `eval` for invoking the command from the variables!

btw here $myvar is a normal string variable. It is not an array like in the above case. It is just that separate arguments are shell escaped with spaces in between.

Hope this helps.

Resources:

- `man bash`
- http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/printf
- http://fvue.nl/wiki/Bash:_Why_use_eval_with_variable_expansion?

Comment: It helped a lot. Thanks for pointing out the need for `eval`. I made a few changes for clarity. Hopefully, they don't violate best practices.

Comment: Nevermind about the edits. The editors say it's too much/too little.  If anyone is interested: `printf`: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/printf `why eval is necessary`: http://fvue.nl/wiki/Bash%3a_Why_use_eval_with_variable_expansion?

Comment: @dgo.a, glad I helped. I've included your resources in the answer. They have nice additions to the man page. But I put `man bash` on first place so users don't forget to look what's supported by their particular bash version.

Answer (score 5):

`$@` is an array. Store it in an array:

```
ar=("$@")
"${ar[@]}"
```

Comment: Where did you learn this answer? I know it's basic, but was it in some `man` or some introductory publication?

Comment: Everything is in `man bash`, but I learned some details and tricks from Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide, too.

Comment: The [BashFAQ at Greg's wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ) is another good reference.